# Header, slider and body views in symfony

Tags: symfony, model-view-controller

**Hello.**

We know that Symfony use MVC. All controlers have own views, but how about slider, header and body view?

I mean that, slider and header is almost the same ( for example - only title is change between view ).

Only 'body' page ( between slider and header ) is changing.

**Question:**

1. How to use almost the same slider and header between views of different controllers (I think that copy sliders and headers is not good way)? I know about inheritance of views but dont know how to use this there.

Comment: Actually, if we spent some time reading the documentation we would know that Symfony does not explicitly "use" MVC.  It considers itself to be a Request/Response framework.  And as far as your question goes, once again documentation to the rescue: http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#template-inheritance-and-layouts

Answer (score 0):

You can read the Templating section from Symfony website [templating section](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html). Twig is the template engine used by Symfony and it supports Template Inheritance which means you can define a base layout and other views can extend the base layout.